# IProvideConfiguration classes e.g. UnicastBusConfig get called multiple times

Tags: c#, nservicebus

I've implemented a class with IProvideConfiguration

When my Bus is creating it gets called 4 times. Since there's logic in there to do some gathering of mappings - that logic is also executed 4 times. Do I manually need to keep a flag with 'Initialized' to prevent it from running multiple times or can I use something within NServiceBus or am I using this wrong?

These are the call stacks that lead to the 4 calls:

```
RZ.Integration.Server.dll!RZ.Integration.Config.NServiceBus.UnicastBusConfigProvider.GetConfiguration() Line 25 C#
NServiceBus.Core.dll!NServiceBus.SettingsExtentions.GetConfigSection<NServiceBus.Config.UnicastBusConfig>(NServiceBus.Settings.ReadOnlySettings settings)   Unknown
NServiceBus.Core.dll!NServiceBus.Features.ForwardReceivedMessages.GetConfiguredForwardMessageQueue(NServiceBus.Features.FeatureConfigurationContext context)    Unknown
NServiceBus.Core.dll!NServiceBus.Features.ForwardReceivedMessages..ctor.AnonymousMethod__0_0(NServiceBus.Features.FeatureConfigurationContext config)   Unknown
NServiceBus.Core.dll!NServiceBus.Features.Feature.CheckPrerequisites(NServiceBus.Features.FeatureConfigurationContext context)  Unknown
NServiceBus.Core.dll!NServiceBus.Features.FeatureActivator.HasAllPrerequisitesSatisfied(NServiceBus.Features.Feature feature, NServiceBus.Features.FeatureDiagnosticData diagnosticData, NServiceBus.Features.FeatureConfigurationContext context)  Unknown
NServiceBus.Core.dll!NServiceBus.Features.FeatureActivator.ActivateFeature(NServiceBus.Features.FeatureActivator.FeatureState featureState, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<NServiceBus.Features.FeatureActivator.FeatureState> featuresToActivate, NServiceBus.Features.FeatureConfigurationContext context)    Unknown
NServiceBus.Core.dll!NServiceBus.Features.FeatureActivator.SetupFeatures(NServiceBus.Features.FeatureConfigurationContext context)  Unknown
NServiceBus.Core.dll!NServiceBus.Configure.Initialize() Unknown
NServiceBus.Core.dll!NServiceBus.Bus.Create(NServiceBus.BusConfiguration configuration) Unknown

RZ.Integration.Server.dll!RZ.Integration.Config.NServiceBus.UnicastBusConfigProvider.GetConfiguration() Line 25 C#
NServiceBus.Core.dll!NServiceBus.SettingsExtentions.GetConfigSection<NServiceBus.Config.UnicastBusConfig>(NServiceBus.Settings.ReadOnlySettings settings)   Unknown
NServiceBus.Core.dll!NServiceBus.Features.TimeoutManagerBasedDeferral.GetTimeoutManagerAddress(NServiceBus.Features.FeatureConfigurationContext context)    Unknown
NServiceBus.Core.dll!NServiceBus.Features.TimeoutManagerBasedDeferral.Setup(NServiceBus.Features.FeatureConfigurationContext context)   Unknown
NServiceBus.Core.dll!NServiceBus.Features.FeatureActivator.ActivateFeature(NServiceBus.Features.FeatureActivator.FeatureState featureState, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<NServiceBus.Features.FeatureActivator.FeatureState> featuresToActivate, NServiceBus.Features.FeatureConfigurationContext context)    Unknown
NServiceBus.Core.dll!NServiceBus.Features.FeatureActivator.SetupFeatures(NServiceBus.Features.FeatureConfigurationContext context)  Unknown
NServiceBus.Core.dll!NServiceBus.Configure.Initialize() Unknown
NServiceBus.Core.dll!NServiceBus.Bus.Create(NServiceBus.BusConfiguration configuration) Unknown

RZ.Integration.Server.dll!RZ.Integration.Config.NServiceBus.UnicastBusConfigProvider.GetConfiguration() Line 25 C#
NServiceBus.Core.dll!NServiceBus.SettingsExtentions.GetConfigSection<NServiceBus.Config.UnicastBusConfig>(NServiceBus.Settings.ReadOnlySettings settings)   Unknown
NServiceBus.Core.dll!NServiceBus.Features.UnicastBus.RegisterMessageOwnersAndBusAddress(NServiceBus.Features.FeatureConfigurationContext context, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Type> knownMessages)    Unknown
NServiceBus.Core.dll!NServiceBus.Features.UnicastBus.Setup(NServiceBus.Features.FeatureConfigurationContext context)    Unknown
NServiceBus.Core.dll!NServiceBus.Features.FeatureActivator.ActivateFeature(NServiceBus.Features.FeatureActivator.FeatureState featureState, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<NServiceBus.Features.FeatureActivator.FeatureState> featuresToActivate, NServiceBus.Features.FeatureConfigurationContext context)    Unknown
NServiceBus.Core.dll!NServiceBus.Features.FeatureActivator.SetupFeatures(NServiceBus.Features.FeatureConfigurationContext context)  Unknown
NServiceBus.Core.dll!NServiceBus.Configure.Initialize() Unknown
NServiceBus.Core.dll!NServiceBus.Bus.Create(NServiceBus.BusConfiguration configuration) Unknown

RZ.Integration.Server.dll!RZ.Integration.Config.NServiceBus.UnicastBusConfigProvider.GetConfiguration() Line 25 C#
NServiceBus.Core.dll!NServiceBus.SettingsExtentions.GetConfigSection<NServiceBus.Config.UnicastBusConfig>(NServiceBus.Settings.ReadOnlySettings settings)   Unknown
NServiceBus.Core.dll!NServiceBus.Transports.Msmq.TimeToBeReceivedOverrideCheck.Run(NServiceBus.Configure config)    Unknown
NServiceBus.Core.dll!NServiceBus.Configure.Initialize() Unknown
NServiceBus.Core.dll!NServiceBus.Bus.Create(NServiceBus.BusConfiguration configuration) Unknown
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the class implementing `IProvideConfiguration` will be created every time a caller tries to access it's configuration (in your case `UnicastBusConfig`). You could keep the first created instance as a static variable around and always return the same config instance when `GetConfiguration` of your `IProvideConfiguration` implementation is called. I'd recommend to move any initialization logic out of the class implementing `IProvideConfiguration`.